# Managed property for number field Sharepoint Online

Tags: indexing, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

i need to index a field in SharePoint Online. This field is of type "Number", but i noticed that if i use the property "refinableint" (of type number), it's not indexed (no result or null value), but if i use the property "refinableDecimal" (of type decimal), a value of "1" indexes with a value of 1000.
For the text type, i use the "refinableString" and it works.

What i am doing wrong? What is the correct way to index this type of field?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce this issue on my end. If I map the crawled property to the managed property "RefinableIntxx" or "RefinableDecimalxx", I can search by the property mormally. There may be somrthing wrong with the search in the backend of your tenant which is controled by Microsoft, you can open a service request in the Microsoft 365 to check it with them.

Comment: I opened a ticket with Microsoft, they say that is probably a bug, maybe related to the international settings (Italy in my case). I'm waiting for the response.